# How do I do a non-standard sort on an Array in C#?

Tags: c#

Array.Sort(test);

Comes out to be

```
_A
_B
_C
A
B
C
```

I reverse it

```
C
B
A
_C
.. You know
```

I want it to be

```
_C
_B
_A
C
B
A
```

So how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your own Comparer like this:

```
public class MyOwnComparer: IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        if (x.StarsWith("_") && !y.StartsWith("_"))
            return 1;
        else if (!x.StartsWith("_") && y.StartsWith("_"))
            return -1;
        else
            return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
Array.Sort(test, new MyOwnComparer()); //sort ascending
var result = test.Reverse(); //now its descending
```

Answer (score 4):

If the built-in Array.Sort() does not sort the way you intend, you can override the  IComparable.CompareTo method.

See this MSDN Article: How to: [Sort Arrays Using Custom Criteria](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9xfdtye.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Both the most efficient and simplest method would make use of the `Comparison<T>` delegate to do it all in one statement.

```
var items = new string[] { "_A", "_B", "_C", "A", "B", "C" };
Array.Sort(items, (a, b) =>
    {
        var aUnderscore = a.StartsWith("_");
        var bUnderscore = b.StartsWith("_");
        if (!(aUnderscore ^ bUnderscore))
            return string.Compare(b, a);
        else if (aUnderscore)
            return -1;
        else if (bUnderscore)
            return +1;
        return 0;
    });
```

In uses lambda expressions, although not LINQ, so the performance hit should not be at all large, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a comparer class that implements IComparer(Of String), then pass an instance of this class as the second parameter of Array.Sort.

Here's a sample code (in VB, sorry for that, but C# code would be similar):

```
Dim str = New String() {"_A", "_B", "_C", "A", "B", "C"}
Array.Sort(str, New SpecialComparer())
```

And here's my SpecialComparer:

```
Private Class SpecialComparer Implements IComparer(Of String)

    Public Function Compare(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String) As Integer
        If x.StartsWith("_") And Not y.StartsWith("_") Then
            Return -1
        ElseIf y.StartsWith("_") And Not x.StartsWith("_") Then
            Return 1
        Else
            Return y.CompareTo(x)
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: I prefer this approach when there is a chance that I'm going to need to sort in more than one way.

Answer (score 1):

Read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) from MSDN about the Sort(Comparison) method, which includes a code example on how to write a custom sorter. I'd recommend copy/pasting it and tweaking it until you get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the fastest way...

```
test = test.Where(x => x.StartsWith("_")).OrderByDescending(x => x).Concat(
       test.Where(x => !x.StartsWith("_")).OrderByDescending(x => x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your criteria I'd just do this (null or empty strings would cause a problem though):

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
items.Sort();
List<string> result = items.FindAll(x => x[0] == '_');
result.AddRange(items.FindAll(x => x[0] != '_'));
```

A sort algorithm that doesn't compare all items may run into issues if you write a comparer that compares "`_`" strings from non-"`_`" strings.  I recall having issues where the resulting order was incorrect because I wrote a comparer that did something similar.

Regardless, a custom comparer:

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
items.Sort(
    delegate(string a, string b)
    {
        if (a[0] == '_' && b[0] == '_')
        {
            return -a.CompareTo(b);
        }
        else if (a[0] == '_')
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else if (b[0] == '_')
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return a.CompareTo(b);
        }
    }
);
```

I also find the former to be more readable, but YMMV.  (Note the minus signs to reverse sort.)